# Exclude certain WebApplicationInitializers in CloudFoundry WAR deploy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

There's a specific version of this question and a general version; I'll ask it both ways.

**Specific Question**

We have a traditional Spring Web application that integrates with Apache Camel that we're pushing to Cloud Foundry. It depends on a custom library that pulls in `spring-cloud-security` (and therefore, `spring-boot-autoconfigure`, among others). When deploying to Cloud Foundry, the Java Autoreconfiguration looks for `WebApplicationInitializer`s on the classpath and one that it finds is `JerseyAutoConfiguration`. When it invokes that particular `WebApplicationInitializer`, we get annotation parsing errors. Is there a way to exclude that one? `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=...)` doesn't work because this isn't happening during the AutoConfiguration step.

**General Question**

Is there a way, via `web.xml` or some other facility, to tell the Java Autoreconfigure code (included via the Java buildpack) to skip executing certain `WebApplicationInitializer`s?

Comment: Interesting question.  Could you post the stack trace / error log that you're getting when you push to CF?  Might help to see exactly what's breaking.

Comment: I imagine it's a classloader issue caused by Jersey not being on the classpath. That's really a bug in Spring Boot so you should report it in github and get it fixed (but my answer is still valid).

Comment: I suspect that's what it is too. I'll see if I can get the code back to a point to reproduce it (I've been refactoring for a couple of days but I have a good save point). I'll definitely do that so I can open the issue in Github.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy the app as an executable instead of as a WAR then there is no scanning for `WebApplicationInitializers` (it's a Spring thing not a buildpack thing).

Comment: So you're suggesting then adding a `main` method with `SpringApplication.run()` ... can that work with a main servlet that is not `DispatcherServlet`? They're using the `CamelHttpTransportServlet` in conjunction with a `ContextLoaderListener`

Comment: (Assuming you are using Spring Boot that is.)

Comment: I'll look into that. Could this also be accomplished with a `SpringBootServletInitializer`? Due to other technical considerations, we're trying to avoid using the embedded servlet container as much as possible.

Comment: If you have concerns about the embedded container I wish you'd say what they are (in github). Anyway the war deployment should be the same. Please at least comment on the github issue.